# How to track time-expenditure for Vim operations?

Tags: vimscript, gvim, microsoft-windows, performance

Is there a `syntime` equivalent **global command** that can track the overall Vim performance? I am having trouble debugging the cause for a set of very-slow file-operations on a Windows machine.

Since these operations are done in an active Vim session, the following syntax that tracks only file-opening events are not enough:
`gvim --startuptime d:\timelog.log the_file`

Answer (score 2):

You can profile and measure time Vim spends on executing functions and scripts. For more details, run `:h profile` in Vim.

Here's an example:

```
profile start ~/vim-profile.log
profile file ~/.vim/*
profile func foo#*
```

This will profile functions that start with `foo#` under `~/.vim/` and log the output in `~/vim-profile.log`.

Comment: I do understand the syntax, but what if I don't have a function to track? I am trying to first find out what has been causing a very-slow file operation (opening a file and switching buffer are taking more than 2 seconds in some occasions). Thus, I am asking for a time-logging method that can yield similar output to the` --startuptime`, but rather for all internal Vim operations.

Comment: @llinfeng Have you tried loading this file with Vim from command-line, including the `--startuptime`?  e.g. `vim SLOWFILE.md --startuptime /tmp/vim.log +q`

Comment: Have just tried what you said, and I saw a detailed list composed of each and every `.vim` files through the `--startuptime``. Yet, no function was mentioned at all. Yet, I have found why my `gvim.exe` is slowing down in my Windows machine: it has to do with the way I start it. On my Windows machine, I use AutoHotKey on a daily basis. For some yet unknown reason, `gvim.exe` processes started by AutoHotKey is SLOW. Yet, `gvim.exe` processes started through the Windows Run window, or the Command Prompt, are fast and responsive.